# yii2: How to load relative path,action,view ... in module

Tags: php, module, yii2

I'm just start working with Yii2.

------------- Problem number 1: load view error -----------------
I have a **Site** module with SiteController and it's views.

```
actionIndex(){
    $this->render('index');
}
```

> It show error: the view ROOT_PATH/views/site/index.php not found (note: ROOT_PATH is driectory in my local).

In init() function in the ROOT_PATH\modules\Site\Module.php file: i added statement to test: `echo $this->getViewPath();`

> Result: ROOT_PATH\modules\Site\views

**I want to ask**: why it do not load index.php in /modules/Site/views folder ??? (It load index.php in ROOT_PATH\views folder so it not found that view file)

------------- Problem number 2: Load action error --------------

When i add to ROOT_PATH\modules\Site\Module.php file: 
    `Yii::$app->setLayoutPath($this->getLayoutPath());`
Now it can load correct view for actionIndex. But links this view do not working:

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']]
]
```

Html is generaated on Front-End:

```
<a href="/site/about">About</a>
```

Why href is **'/site/about'**, i want this value will be **"site/site/about"**

Answer (score 0):

to call 'about' link you have to create about.php in views/site and create a function which name must be actionAbout() in sitecontroller

in sitecontroller

```
public function actionAboute()
{
$this->render('about');
}
```

in index.php

```
<?= Html::a('About', ['value'=>Url::to('index.php?r=site/about')]) ?>
```

and for load view problem check your config file and cookieValidationKey once.

Comment: i know it. I don't understand why it load incrrect view for actionIndex().

Answer (score 0):

All Modules search for the view templates in their module path. 
So if you have a module named "site" and inside the module a controller named "SiteController" it searches the view in the folder

`ROOT_PATH\modules\site\views\site\`

`ROOT_PATH\modules\[modulename]\views\[controlername]`

If you directly have the controllers in your application in  \controllers the viewpath will be

`ROOT_PATH\modules\views\site\`

`ROOT_PATH\modules\views\[controlername]`

a Link in the view which starts with / always starts from the root. in your case you just need `['about']` to link to the same controller (and same module).

if you link to a controller in a another module you also have to give the module name which is also in your case `site`.

`['/site/site/about']` would also link to your site controller in your site module. But as i mentioned above if you want to link to the same controller in the same module it isn't needed.

You can find the guide about routing and URL creation here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Thank for your reply.
my module structure:
ROOT_PATH\
     modules\
          Site\
                 controllers\
                          SiteController.php (have actionIndex)
                 views\
                          site\
                                 index.php

Why in indexAction i call $this->render('index'); It do not load correct. I load ROOT_PATH\views\index.php